# Eclipse SearchDialog Changes as soon as the Dialog is being called

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

My Requirement is like to change the Eclipse Default SearchDialog, so as soon as any user opens the Eclipse Menu , Search>Search, the window/wizard opens should be the customized one ,
How to make this scenario possible.
Is there any Extension point which handles all startup operation for a wizard, so that I could call that and any time the dialog is getting called , I will override and make my changes.

Answer (score 0):

By using `org.eclipse.search.searchResultViewPages` extension point you can define your own search result page and other required class to contribute to the built-in Eclipse search "mechanism".